# apple musickit user token

Tags: swift3, ios10.3, apple-musickit

how to create music user token for Apple musikkit API's. Each time execute

```
SKCloudServiceController().requestPersonalizationToken(forClientToken: developerTokenString) { (userToken, error) in
if let token = userToken {
       //
   } else {
       debugPrint("user token error \(error!.localizedDescription)")
   }
}
```

with developer token getting error

> "The operation couldn’t be completed. (SKErrorDomain error 7.)"

Is there any way to check that my developer token is valid or not.

Comment: Good question, haven't found the answer yet too.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applemusicapi/getting_keys_and_creating_tokens) you can use the following command to test your token in terminal:

```
curl -v -H 'Authorization: Bearer [developer token]' "https://api.music.apple.com/v1/catalog/us/songs/203709340"
```